# How to grant delegated user pemissions to managed-service-identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-managed-identity

**TL;DR**

How can I delegate my user permissions to a service principal in Azure Ad when the usual `interactive` way (e.g. web app with consent screen popup) is not feasible? This is because I cannot configure the MSI in the Azure Portal properly to work that way.

**More detail**

I want to grant an application permission to access the Graph API on behalf of a user. Usually, this is a [well-documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) scenario in which you create an app registration, acquire `delegated user permissions` by asking permission for the needed scopes, and then use these permissions in the app.

The app that needs Graph access is a background service that is to work on its own without user intervention/activity. For this use case, the common approach is to use `application permissions`. In my case this is not feasible, because application permissions require admin-consent and are all-or-nothing kind of permissions. There is no way this will be granted for me. Rightfully so, because its overkill.

But on the other hand that's really a pity. A pity, because I've found an [example](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-with-microsoft-graph-api-using-managed-service-identity/) on how to assign Graph API application permissions directly to a `Managed Service Identity` rather than to a self-registered app. And my service (as an Azure Functions app) already has a MSI assigned to it. So this would be the perfect fit, b then again, there is no way I'll get those application permissions.

**So what is the workaround?** We have this one `user principal` which has all the required permissions we need for our background service. What I want to do is to delegate this user's permissions to the Function App/MSI. In order to do this, I used [this SPA-template by the MSAL team](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular) to have something that will prompt me the permissions popup.

This however failed because the `implicit oauth flow` was not enabled. To remedy this, you usually need to update the app manifest in the portal. However, since this is a MANAGED service identity, and not a self-registered one, the MSI is not listed in the portal under app registrations. So I cannot set this property to true.

Doing the same via Azure CLI also failed because apparently the MSI is not identified as an app.

```
az ad app update --oauth2-allow-implicit-flow true --id <appId_of_MSI>
```

This yields the following error:

`ResourceNotFoundError: Resource '<appId_of_MSI>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.`

It shows fine when doing this

```
az ad sp show --id <appId_of_MSI>
```

So in summary: I cannot complete the process of delegating that user's permissions `interactively`. Is there any other way? Maybe via CLI?

The fallback the solution is to create a separate unmanaged/self-registered app identity. But I want to really avoid this because then I would need to manage and rotate client (app) credentials again, which the MSI took care of for me.

Why o why can't I just assign fine-scoped application permissions

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience Managed Identities don't support the scenario you are suggesting.
They do not have an app registration and in that way cannot authenticate users interactively.

I would go with your fallback solution; a normal app registration and use that to access Graph API on behalf of the user.
This is what we do in our projects at least.
App permissions -> Managed Identity if possible. Delegated permissions -> normal app registration + secret/certificate in Key Vault, retrieved with Managed Identity.

Comment: Thanks juunas. Then I do have a definite action plan to pursue. Do you automate the credential rotation of the registered app?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for a scenario where; i want to delegate the activities of granting api admin/user consent, trough a custom EntraId role, without giving away Global Admin priv.

This seem to work for granting delegated type permissions to system assigned identities:

```
# All principals in tenant
$params = @{
    "ClientId" = "guid string" # the system assigned managed identity objectId
    "ConsentType" = "AllPrincipals" # grant admin consent for all user principals in the tenant
    "ResourceId" = "guid string" # the service principal id of API/EntApp that exposes the permissions ie. Microsoft Graph (dont use the ApplicaitonID/ClientID)
    "Scope" = "Group.Read.All" # the actual permission
  }
  
# Specific principals in tenant
  $params = @{
    "ClientId" = "guid string"
    "ConsentType" = "Principal" # so not AllPrincipals
    "PrincipalId" = "guid string" # the specific user principals in the tenant
    "ResourceId" = "guid string"
    "Scope" = "Group.Read.All"
  }
  
New-MgOauth2PermissionGrant -BodyParameter $params | 
    Format-List Id, ClientId, ConsentType, ExpiryTime, PrincipalId, ResourceId, Scope
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/tutorial-grant-delegated-api-permissions?view=graph-powershell-1.0#step-3-grant-delegated-permissions-to-the-client-enterprise-application